In this question, why is the first image centered but the second is not?
It's OK either way, but I'd rather have them in the same.
Hitchhikers Guide: was Marvin the computer that deep thought said would follow it?

Both images are left aligned, it's just that the first one has black bars around it that make it look more centered.

They were, originally, both aligned left. The upper picture had large obnoxious black bars that made it look like it was aligned into the middle.

I've fixed it, although the pictures don't really add anything to the question and should probably be deleted.

"the pictures don't really add anything to the question and should probably be deleted" - well said, although the same applies to a lot of unnecessary pictures that you've edited into other questions over the years :-)

@Randal'Thor - Touché, sirrah.
